# Troubles importing BetterPickers Library to Eclipse

Tags: android, import, libraries

I'm trying to import [`this`](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers) library to my workspace in `Eclipse`, and so far I'm getting that many resources `are not found` in the files.

The library mentions that it depends on [`ViewPagerIndicator`](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) to work, which is imported fine in my `workspace`.

I tried cleaning/building the project again and nothing. For the sample app in the BetterPickers library, I added `ViewPagerIndicator` and its own library using `Project Properties -> Android -> isLibrary -> add`

The picture shows how my package explorer and the java files from the library look like:

**`library` is BetterPickers library, `libraryV` is ViewPagersIndicator's library and `ListSample` is the example for BetterPickers.**

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a few months back, and I forgot to post the answer. But, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18344404/1188208) it is.

Answer (score 0):

The library in question is set to build with the new Gradle-based build system, so it may take some work to shoehorn it into Eclipse.

Beyond that, make sure that your library project is set to build with API Level 16 or higher, as [that is what the `build.gradle` requests](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers/blob/master/library/build.gradle).

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work. Even though that everything seems to be on its respective folder, there are many resources that are not found in the Library. The project is only failing to load because of its library errors. So, will I need to change to Android Studio? (I really don't want to)

Comment: @LuisLavieri: The errors in your screenshot are because your library project's build target is too low, from what I can tell.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I'm following you. I already tried changing the build target to the example in properties -> android -> build target = 16. But, nothing. The java files from the library are completely broken.