# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo with BetterPickers library

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, runtimeexception

My app is throwing a`RuntimeException`after adding [this](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers) library. Now, for example [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688277/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo) suggest that I have to declare the`Activity`in my`Manifest`. How can I do that with BetterPickers? [here](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers/blob/master/sample/AndroidManifest.xml) is the`Manifest`file of the sample app from the library, and here is mine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <!-- First item is for saving state while rotating -->
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" 
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:name="com.foodbuilder.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Searchable configuration -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**EDIT**: This is my LogCat

```
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.foodbuilder/com.foodbuilder.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.foodbuilder.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.foodbuilder-2.apk
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2224)
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.foodbuilder.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.foodbuilder-2.apk
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
08-20 14:32:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(24371):    ... 11 more
```

And this is what I tried:

```
<activity>
...
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="com.doomonafireball.betterpickers"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Here is how I added my Library:

[image]

And also here is my implementation:

```
package com.foodbuilder;

import com.doomonafireball.betterpickers.numberpicker.NumberPickerBuilder;
import com.doomonafireball.betterpickers.numberpicker.NumberPickerDialogFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TablesDialogFragment.NoticeDialogListener, NumberPickerDialogFragment.NumberPickerDialogHandler {

...
private NumberPickerBuilder numberPickerBuilder;
...
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: whats the package line for MainActivity.java, this should match what you have in the manifest (com.foodbuilder. )

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand your suggestion. Is there something that is not matching?

Comment: the package line in MainActivity.java (it is before the import lines).  Can you post that?

Comment: package com.foodbuilder;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my God. After two days of battling with this library. I went to the library's `properties -> Build Path -> Order and Export and "Unchecked" android-support-v4.jar.` I don't even know why that was checked.